# Access IndexedDB from Web Workers

Tags: firefox, web-worker, indexeddb

I can not seem to figure out HOW to use `indexedDB` inside web worker. I've tried a lot of different ways, but `indexedDB` is always `"undefined"` in worker scope. I thought it was supposed to be accessible via `indexedDB` or `self.indexedDB`???

```
self.indexedDB = self.indexedDB || self.msIndexedDB || self.mozIndexedDB || self.webkitIndexedDB || self.OIndexedDB;

indexedDB = indexedDB || msIndexedDB || mozIndexedDB || webkitIndexedDB || OIndexedDB;
```

all are `undefined` ... i even iterated through the properties of the self object, and there was no `indexedDB` property or method. fwiw, i'm using ff 18, AND, ff nightly (21a), and i tried it with chrome.

Comment: firefox does support now indexeddb in worker: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701634

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update September 2015:
Accessing IndexedDB from web worker in Firefox is now possible:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701634

If you want to use IndexedDB in chrome just use the following line:

```
indexedDB = typeof window == 'object' ? window.indexedDB : webkitIndexedDB;
```

Comment: thanks a million. i searched all night and never found that. it looks like it's going to be a WHILE before it's available ... well, i've only wasted 1 day of my time ... back to the drawing board ...

Comment: np, if you need basic examples of IndexedDB usage check out this project https://github.com/denimf/IndexedDbToDo

Comment: And I just noticed that you are a new user so you should accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: i'd love to, but, i don't know how, lmao. i was going to do that as soon as you answered the first time, but i don't see the option [o_O]

Comment: there should be accept answer check box like button on the left side of the answer http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: Deni, fyi, as of chrome 24 (current stable channel) you don't need that stuff, `indexedDB` is no longer prefixed in chrome. A straight `indexedDB` will suffice, no matter if you're running in a worker or not.

Comment: thanks dgrogan i haven't noticed that, i've been using the same if since chrome 17 :)

Comment: What about Safari?

Answer (score 4):

[indexeddb](/questions/tagged/indexeddb) **is accessible** from Web Workers since [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) `37` (released March 31st, 2015).

> **IndexedDB**
>   Database to store records holding simple values and hierarchical objects.
>
> [image: IndexedDB API WebWorkers screenshot]

See [Functions and classes available to Web Workers (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers)